# Feeding several legal acts (PDF's) into a language model for the purpose of returning a case to present to a defendant

Tags: gpt, embeddings

I used ChatGPT to give me all relevant acts, rules, laws, regulations, etc, on a specific legal topic.

I retrieved all of the above from the U.K. official legislation website as PDF's.

I need a method for feeding all of those into 'some kind of AI' to return to me a professional case to present to a defendant.

I'm aware of such 'services' as LangChain, HuggingFace, PineCone, and of course ChatGPT and Bard. I have used ChatGPT Turbo over the API before.

Please assist.

Thank you.

Comment: ChatGPT is not a lawyer. If you need to sue someone, it is highly recommended that you hire a solicitor. Relying on the output of a generative AI system in court (or in any situation, for that matter) is ill-advised; in one case ChatGPT wrote a legal filing that cited nonexistent cases as precedent. If you know enough about the law to verify GPT's output, then it would be better to simply write the document yourself, but it is still highly recommended to hire a solicitor.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. Yes, I'm aware of the concerns you raised. My intention is to convince the counter-party to come to their senses. I would of course seek the services of appropriate professionals should I need to take my case to court. Thanks again.